# devise: undefined method `router_name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am getting the error

```
undefined method `router_name' for nil:NilClass
```

right at the homepage of my app which was working fine until now

```
</div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:id => 'registration'}) do |f| %>
          <%= f.error_notification %>
          <div class="form-inputs" style="margin: 13px">
            <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true, :input_html => {:id => 'email_new_user', :autocomplete => :on} %>
```

From the console:

```
Processing by WelcomeController#homepage as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
  User Load (4449.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "bb789076-afd7-43e9-a91c-37ace112183b"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (44899.5ms)  SELECT "distribs"."city" FROM "distribs" WHERE "distribs"."position" = $1  [["position", "Pilote"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 103073ms (ActiveRecord: 96629.8ms)




NameError (uninitialized constant Todo::UserId):

app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:25:in `homepage'
```

And the row 25 of the welcome controller is :

```
  @todos = Todo.where(user_id: current_user.id)
```

It seems that any page/module in the app that require `user_id/current_user.id` is sudently not working.

I have not done any change on devise components. I am using RubyMine.

Does anybody see what is wrong in the simple_form declaration ?

Comment: Could you attach the relevant log request and error on `rails server`?

Comment: Tuan Tuan, please ignore this question, someone renamed all the column user_id to user, that is why the whole thing crashed, all the tables were affected. Apologies for the waste of time. It is now fixed. Thank you. (You can rate -1 :) )